# Run C++ in Visual Studio Code without opening it with `code .` from CMD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I set up VSCode to compile C++, but in order to be able to run it, I first have to open CMD, navigate to the location of the `.cpp` file I want to open and then run `code .` (This opens VSCode and then I can compile the file with `Ctrl+Shift+B`.) This is tedious and it would be wonderful if I had a script that enabled me to run C++ without having to do the above procedure every time.

Thank you for your help. :)

**EDIT**

This is my `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to provide more information about your issue.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow! In order to answer this question, we would need to know what build system VSCode is configured to use to compile your code when you press `Ctrl+Shift+B`. VSCode doesn't have a single method for compiling, there are many options, each with their own way of running from the command line.

Comment: Also explain why you need VSCode to run your built C++ at all. Is it not built as an exe that you could run from CMD directly?

Comment: @Romen I was a bit imprecise. I don't need VSCode to *run* the built C++ `.exe`. I need it to compile the `.exe` file in the first place.

Comment: @effect I'm using g++ to build my `.exe` files.

Comment: just run the same bulid commands that vscode is running? If you use a build system like cmake then that'll probably make your life easier

Comment: @God bless, so `g++` is the compiler, but there's usually something below VSCode that instructs how to call `g++`. Examples include cmake, make, or visual studio project files (.vcxproj). Could you edit your question and show what the VSCode build task json file looks like? How did you setup VSCode?

Comment: @effect OK, I will append my `task.json` to my question. Also, I set up VSCode for C++ with [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).

Comment: @effect Also, it seems strange to me that CMD recognises `gdb --version`, but not `g++ --version`, even though I added `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to PATH. `g++` is in `bin`. (Should there be another backslash after `bin`?)

Comment: ***Should there be another backslash after bin?*** No

Comment: Not sure what's up with your path, but for now you can invoke g++ just by giving the full path to it, `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe`, just like you are in the .json file, although on the Windows command line the double backslashes aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case with a single `.cpp` file and g++ installed, you should be able to compile from the command line using a command similar to below:

```
g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g <.cpp file name> -o <output binary name>
```

Make sure to replace `<.cpp file name>` with your actual filename and `<output binary name>` with whatever you want to name your executable.

It appears you are first starting to learn how to develop in C++. This solution above should work for now.

When you start to write bigger programs and decide to split your source code into multiple files, you will eventually want to learn how to use a build system that can help automate the compilation of multiple source files. A popular build system is [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make), this would probably be a good tool to learn. You can write `makefiles` which instruct how to build the code, and then VSCode can be configured to use `make` to read the `makefiles` and build the code.

Comment: The problem is, none of my `g++` commands compile. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470977/i-cant-run-g-from-cmd-despite-having-it-added-in-path). P.S. I got the thing working even without typing in the full path to `g++.exe`, but it's tedious. Thank you for your time and help that you have offered. :)